# How to deal with big numbers

Tags: c#, integer

I'm currently implementing an idle click game and I have a problem with big numbers.
I'm using Unity with C#.

How can I handle big numbers ?

I already use a function that deal with big number but it has a limit (Integer limit). I want to have a function without a limit.

```
if (rawNumber < 1000000.0) {
        return rawNumber.ToString (formatString);
    }
    ScientificNotation scientificNotation = ScientificNotation.FromDouble (rawNumber);
    ushort adjustedExponent = (ushort)((scientificNotation.exponent / 3) - 1);
    string prefix = "";
    if (adjustedExponent < 10) {
        prefix = latin[adjustedExponent - 1];
    }
    else {
        ushort hundredsPlace = (ushort)(adjustedExponent / 100);
        ushort tensPlace = (ushort)((adjustedExponent / 10) % 10);
        ushort onesPlace = (ushort)(adjustedExponent % 10);
        string onesString = (onesPlace > 0) ? ones[onesPlace - 1] : "";
        string modifier = "";
        if ((onesPlace == 7) || (onesPlace == 9)) {
            if (tensPlace > 0) {
                if ((tensPlace == 2) || (tensPlace == 8)) {
                    modifier = "m";
                }
                else if (tensPlace != 9) {
                    modifier = "n";
                }
            }
            else if (hundredsPlace > 0) {
                if (hundredsPlace == 8) {
                    modifier = "m";
                }
                else if (hundredsPlace != 9) {
                    modifier = "n";
                }
            }
        }
        if ((onesPlace == 3) || (onesPlace == 6)) {
            if (tensPlace > 0) {
                if ((tensPlace == 2) || (tensPlace == 3) || (tensPlace == 4) || (tensPlace == 5) || (tensPlace == 8)) {
                    modifier = ((onesPlace == 6) && (tensPlace == 8)) ? "x" : "s";
                }
            }
            else if (hundredsPlace > 0) {
                if ((hundredsPlace == 1) || (hundredsPlace == 3) || (hundredsPlace == 4) || (hundredsPlace == 5) || (hundredsPlace == 8)) {
                    modifier = ((onesPlace == 6) && ((tensPlace == 1) || (tensPlace == 8))) ? "x" : "s";
                }
            }
        }
        string tensString = (tensPlace > 0) ? tens[tensPlace - 1] : "";
        string hundredsString = (hundredsPlace > 0) ? hundreds[hundredsPlace - 1] : "";
        prefix = string.Format ("{0}{1}{2}{3}", onesString, modifier, tensString, hundredsString);
    }

    double adjustedSignificand = scientificNotation.significand * Math.Pow (10, scientificNotation.exponent % 3);
    double integralPart = Math.Truncate (adjustedSignificand);
    //return string.Format("{0} {1}llion", (((adjustedSignificand - integralPart) > maxFractional) ? integralPart + maxFractional : adjustedSignificand).ToString (formatString), prefix.TrimEnd ('a'));
    return string.Format("{0} {1}", (((adjustedSignificand - integralPart) > maxFractional) ? integralPart + maxFractional : adjustedSignificand).ToString(formatString), prefix);
    //return "" + " " + "";

}
```

What should I do ?

My "solution" is to have an int array and implement some logic that uses the different arrays positions (don't know the logic yet). For example, I'll start with the [0]. When that int gets to the max value, I'll start use the [1].

And how should I handle in a way that it appears 1000 = 1k . 1000000 = 1M.. 1 aa, 1 ab, 1 ac etc

Can anybody help me or giving me a tip ?

Thank you so much.

Comment: try System.Numerics.BigInteger.

Comment: How big a number? How precise?  A long gets you +/- 9 times 10 to the 18 (counting on my fingers).  A decimal gets you 128 bits of number with a huge range.  Doubles sacrifice precision for range.  Why do you want a "big number"?

Comment: Idle click games with big numbers usually use a double as base type for their values. Even when they run with natural numbers, but their range till ±1,7 × 10^308 is normally enough for them.

Comment: I dont have the BigInteger in unity, I tried System.Numerics.BigInteger and it doesn't work.

Comment: And How should I handle in a way that it appears 1000 = 1k . 1000000 = 1M.. 1 aa, 1 ab, 1 ac etc

Answer (score 0):

Look at this: [C# Integral types table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/integral-types-table)

Like Leandro already mentioned:

> Use the System.Numerics.BigInteger class to represent an arbitrarily large signed integer.

Comment: When I do that I get an error. "The Type 'Numerics' does not exists in the namespace 'System'"

Comment: You have to add a reference to System.Numerics in your project. Click Add Reference, Assemblys, Framework und choose System.Numerics.